# Empty array output result

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I hope you can help identify where I am making mistakes in the following code:

```
    public function yee() {

    $json = array();
    $params = array(
                'token'             => $this->_token,
                'receiver_name'         => 'Test Name',

                'sender_city'           => 'copenhagen',
                'sender_country'        => 'DK',
                'order_id'              => 150
            );

    $ch = curl_init();      
    $query = http_build_query($params);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::API_ENDPOINT . '/' . 'shipments/imported_shipment');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $output = curl_exec ($ch);
            $http_code = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close ($ch);

            $output = json_decode($output, true);

            if ($http_code != 200){
                if(is_array($output['message'])){
                        $json['error'] = $output['message'];
                }else{
                        $json['error'] = $output['message'];
                }
            } else {
                $json['error'] = "Import Successully";
            } 
    return $output;
        }
    }
```

I have this in my class.php file, along with a few more lines doing the authentication.

Then I try to call the function after initializing it:

```
$testObject->yee();
echo $testObject->yee(); ?>
```

The authentication part works correctly, as I'm also outputting tokens and a few other variables, however when I echo the yee() function - all it displays is "Array"

In case you didn't notice, I am extremely green in JSON/API territory, and my PHP skills are rusty at best. So I am hoping for any and all pointers to lead me closer to solving this. Thanks!

Comment: Thats because the return value is an array! You cant echo an array. If you just want to see its contents for debugging, then user `var_dump($output);`

Comment: Thanks a bunch, makes sense now I think about it like that.
Seems to work fine with a var_dump of the output, and you were correct in assuming I was debugging. Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you already get the idea from steve's comment. You just can't echo an array. 
Please use,

```
var_dump($output);
//or
print_r($output);
```

to debug.

Or if you just want to stick on `echo`, 
try:

```
echo implode( ', ', $output);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for spelling it out for me!

Answer (score 0):

> all it displays is "Array"

When you try to `echo` (or `print`) an array, PHP will simply display the word "Array".
This is because echo and print are not designed to run through an array displaying out it's keys and values. They are simply to output "scalar" types, and arrays are "compound" types.

See here for differences:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php

---

Trying to echo an array will also produce a "Notice" in your logs, such as:

> PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion

It's essential to view your PHP error logs as a developer because this is PHP's *feedback* telling you things it found which might be a problem, and this notice would have told you of the issue - even if just a starting point to search Stack and Google.

---

To display an array, use [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I thought it was enough to run with php debug on, will refer to error logs more often in the future!